# When user create account it goes to home activity instead of log in activity, How to avoid this?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When User clicks on to create an account, after completion of task it should go to LogIn activity but instead, it directly takes it to the home activity (without asking for login credentials).

I wrote in the intent name of login activity (in create account button)

(I also wrote the code which checks user is logged in or not on LogIn activity, if that info is needed)

Following is the code in create account button :

```
cma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                //getting the data
                username= nun.getText().toString().trim();
                status= sta.getText().toString().trim();
                emailid= ei.getText().toString().trim();
                courses= cou.getText().toString().trim();
                year = yr.getSelectedItem().toString();
                dateofbirth= dob.getText().toString().trim();
                collegeid= cid.getText().toString().trim();
                password= pw1.getText().toString().trim();
                cpass= pw2.getText().toString().trim();
                int selectedId = gender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                sexgender = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                final String gender = sexgender.getText().toString().trim();

                if (circularImageView.getDrawable() != null) {
                    cma.setText("Creating Fresh Account....");
                    createAccProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //get image from imageview
                    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) circularImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    //image compress
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                    data = baos.toByteArray();
                    String filePathAndName="ProfilePictures/"+"profile_"+ emailid;

                    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(filePathAndName);
                    ref.putBytes(data)
                            //ERROR on Line Below
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    //Success to firebase storage
                                    Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                                    while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                                    downloadUri = uriTask.getResult().toString();

                                    if (uriTask.isSuccessful()) {
                                        mauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailid,cpass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task){
                                                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    //Custom Field save code
                                                    Student info = new Student(username,status,emailid,year,courses,gender,dateofbirth,collegeid,downloadUri);
                                                    reference.child(username).setValue(info).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task){
                                                            createAccProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"Account successfully Created !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                Intent i = new Intent(Sign_up.this, LogIn.class);
                                                                startActivity(i);
                                                            } else{
                                                                String errorMessage = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                                Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this, "Error: " + errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                    //End custom field
                                                } else{
                                                    Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                                //Authentication Stuff
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this, "Failed Uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                }
                else { }
                //Button Brackets
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sabet Chowdhury told

According to documentation:

If the new account was created, the user is also signed in. In the callback, you can use the getCurrentUser method to get the user's account data.

Solution is by doing following changes to task.isSuccessful code:

```
if(task.isSuccessful()) {
Toast.makeText(Sign_up.this,"Account successfully Created !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//BY ADDING THE FOLLOWING LINE IT WILL SIGN OUT THE USER AND ULTIMATELY WILL LAUNCH LOGIN ACTIVITY
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

Intent i = new Intent(Sign_up.this, LogIn.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth):

> If the new account was created, the user is also signed in. In the callback, you can use the getCurrentUser method to get the user's account data.

So when you are checking whether the user is logged in or not in the Login Activity after successful account creation, it is finding the user as logged in and proceeding to the Home Activity.

Comment: So, would there be any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Atharva_I I can see that you have already found a way. Congratulations!